# Parent and child custom post types without options on parent

Tags: custom-post-types

This might sound an odd one but wondering if the following scenario is possible at all within WP.

Would like for example a parent custom post type of :

Product Type 1

Underneath it I only want options to have 2 custom post type children within it:

News, Reviews (which could be expanded going forward)

Product types could then be expanded as well but they are separated by their CPTs in WP.

Wouldnt want any other post options for the parent only for the children so no add post under Product Type 1 only under News and Reviews. The CPTs would auto create a permalink structure for /product-type-1/news/ ..reviews/

Is this possible or am I thinking about this all wrong? Its to go into an existing site which is mainly powered by another CMS. It has sections already for say domain.com/product-type-1/ with other areas powered by the main CMS. Was hoping to them piggy back in for domain.com/product-type-1/news/ and ..reviews/ which htaccess will handle sending to WP instead.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up thinking about this from another way creating 2 subtypes {type}_reviews and {type}_news and changing the admin menu putting one under the admin menu of the other. The slugs are then altered using the slug customisation in the CPT settings.